# When running the pig script in local mode it gives me error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-pig

I have a problem i am trying to execute pig command in local mode I am using pig -x local and trying to execute a dump statment but its giving me error please have a look and explain to me, another problem is when I am running the same command dump b; in mapreduce mode the command is running fine and its showing me the results i wonder why its not running in local mode please have a look:-

```
 [dead@master ~]$ pig -x local
17/04/20 16:00:53 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
17/04/20 16:00:53 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked LOCAL as the ExecType
2017-04-20 16:00:53,772 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.16.0 (r1746530) compiled Jun 01 2016, 23:10:49
2017-04-20 16:00:53,772 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /opt/hadoop/pig_1492684253771.log
2017-04-20 16:00:53,826 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /opt/hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2017-04-20 16:00:54,150 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
2017-04-20 16:00:54,322 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Pig Script ID for the session: PIG-default-f6e00222-79c4-4e12-a2f1-c9404e17c69c
2017-04-20 16:00:54,322 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - ATS is disabled since yarn.timeline-service.enabled set to false
grunt> data = load '/books.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (booknum:int, author:chararray, title:chararray, published:int);
grunt> b = foreach data generate author,title;
grunt> dump b;
2017-04-20 16:01:06,219 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2017-04-20 16:01:06,424 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2017-04-20 16:01:06,493 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.ColumnPruneVisitor - Columns pruned for data: $0, $3
2017-04-20 16:01:06,600 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - Selected heap (Tenured Gen) of size 699072512 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489350752, usageThreshold = 489350752
2017-04-20 16:01:06,758 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2017-04-20 16:01:06,821 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2017-04-20 16:01:06,821 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2017-04-20 16:01:06,945 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2017-04-20 16:01:07,013 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2017-04-20 16:01:07,049 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2017-04-20 16:01:07,090 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2017-04-20 16:01:07,141 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2017-04-20 16:01:07,141 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2017-04-20 16:01:07,141 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Distributed cache not supported or needed in local mode. Setting key [pig.schematuple.local.dir] with code temp directory: /tmp/1492684267141-0
2017-04-20 16:01:07,242 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2017-04-20 16:01:07,315 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-04-20 16:01:07,763 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2017-04-20 16:01:07,813 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage - Using PigTextInputFormat
2017-04-20 16:01:07,860 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-dead/mapred/staging/dead1668871356/.staging/job_local1668871356_0001
2017-04-20 16:01:07,893 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:DefaultJobName got an error while submitting 
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: file:/books.csv
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/books.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:265)
    ... 18 more
2017-04-20 16:01:07,898 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local1668871356_0001
2017-04-20 16:01:07,898 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases b,data
2017-04-20 16:01:07,898 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: data[1,7],b[-1,-1] C:  R: 
2017-04-20 16:01:07,972 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2017-04-20 16:01:08,113 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2017-04-20 16:01:08,114 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_local1668871356_0001 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2017-04-20 16:01:08,114 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2017-04-20 16:01:08,142 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-04-20 16:01:08,142 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
2017-04-20 16:01:08,142 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2017-04-20 16:01:08,143 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.7.2   0.16.0  dead    2017-04-20 16:01:07 2017-04-20 16:01:08 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local1668871356_0001    b,data  MAP_ONLY    Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: file:/books.csv
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/books.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:265)
    ... 18 more
    file:/tmp/temp-1274993195/tmp-1105974594,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/books.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp-1274993195/tmp-1105974594"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local1668871356_0001


2017-04-20 16:01:08,144 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2017-04-20 16:01:08,147 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias b. Backend error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
Details at logfile: /opt/hadoop/pig_1492684253771.log
```

Comment: Your log looks suspicious. You are loading `/temp` but the error is for `/tmp` that too on HDFS. Doesn't look like you're in local.

Comment: i havE Edited the code pleAse look at it again

Comment: you are trying to load `books.csv` from the root of your file system. It doesn't exist there and that's why you are getting the error. Try giving the full path of `books.csv` while in local mode. It should work.

Comment: ok will give it a try. Thanks for the quick response